# How to store some data in array from another json data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to store only renewal dates from given array, is there any way  to store renewal dates in another array . I tried

```js
    const rnDates = [res.result.renewals.renewal_date];
    this.setState({rn_dates:rnDates}).
```

But it shows undefined. If anyone knows how to store specific data from given object array

```
Object {
      "renewals": Array [
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-24",
          "contact": "6458766452",
          "created_at": "2020-08-25 10:01:28",
          "email": "Hgg@gmail.com",
          "id": "46",
          "name": "Test4",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-30",
          "tenure": "Virar",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-24",
          "contact": "6458796454",
          "created_at": "2020-08-24 17:15:21",
          "email": "R@gmail.com",
          "id": "45",
          "name": "Test2 ",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-30",
          "tenure": "Andheri",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-24",
          "contact": "6465789797",
          "created_at": "2020-08-24 17:14:21",
          "email": "Td@gmail.com",
          "id": "44",
          "name": "Test",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-30",
          "tenure": "Dahisar",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-24",
          "contact": "6458879767",
          "created_at": "2020-08-24 14:39:27",
          "email": "Om@gmail.com",
          "id": "43",
          "name": "Omkar palace",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-30",
          "tenure": "Borivali",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-24",
          "contact": "6458766497",
          "created_at": "2020-08-24 11:57:53",
          "email": "Mv@gmail.com",
          "id": "42",
          "name": "Mohak Vila",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-28",
          "tenure": "Andheri",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
        Object {
          "active_status": "1",
          "added_by": "91",
          "agreement_date": "2020-08-23",
          "contact": "6458799464",
          "created_at": "2020-08-23 12:19:00",
          "email": "Di@gmail.com",
          "id": "41",
          "name": "Sai palace",
          "renewal_date": "2020-08-30",
          "tenure": "Dadar",
          "under_user": "91",
        },
      ],
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear from your question but perhaps `mDates = res.result.renewals.map(o => o.renewal_date);`?

Comment: i want to store only renewal dates from given object in the array name of rn_dates[], i dont want store all  data

Comment: `res.result.renewals` is an array of objects. So `res.result.renewals.renewal_date` is undefined. You should do what Nick suggests above.

Answer (score 1):

The field `res.result.renewals` is an array of objects. So `res.result.renewals.renewal_date` is undefined.

As suggested in one of the comments, you need this:

```
let rnDates = res.result.renewals.map(o => o.renewal_date);
```